# Pytesseract not recognising numbers

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read numbers from a picture with pytesseract.
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread(r'bild4.jpg', 2)

[ret, bw_img] = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
imgplot = plt.imshow(bw_img)
plt.show()

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(bw_img, config='digits')
print("Text: " + text)
```

[image: This is the Picture I use]

I tried many ways to preprocess the image, the best I got is:
"673
504 .
5 552"
Only the last line is correct.
Without the config='digits' I get:
"673 ost

Fir 504 .

5 552

ii"

I tried with black and withe only, witch is really easy to read for me as a human, but it don't recognice numbers at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [inRange thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

1. Read the image and convert it to the HSV color-scale

```py
bgr = cv2.imread("JSe5v.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

2. Initialize mask and kernel

```py
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 244]), np.array([179, 35, 255]))
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
```

3. Remove the background using mask and kernel

```py
dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(dilated, mask)
```

The result will be:

[image]

If you read it with [psm mode 6](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

```
675 OS!
312504
5 552
```

1st line second part is not correct "51" is recognized as "S!"

You could look for [improving the tesseract accuracy](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

bgr = cv2.imread("JSe5v.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 244]), np.array([179, 35, 255]))
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(dilated, mask)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config="--psm 6")
print(text)
```

Comment: Thank! Had this preprocessing before too, but seems like psm mode is doint the Job!